# JVM LinkageError and Signature difference

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, urlclassloader, linkageerror

I have a tomcat application starting with a set of jars in the classpath.

Assume ClassA, ClassB, ClassC are used after startup. So, these classes are loaded into the JVM. All these classes are loaded from different jars from the same folder.

Now, I can use `ClassB.method()` from ClassA. It works perfectly.

Now, I add more jars from a different folder to the classpath at runtime. In these jars also, there is ClassB. The ClassB loaded during startup and this are different version.

Now, when I use `ClassB.method()` from ClassA I get LinkageError.

I get the error even if both the jars are same version.

When the new jar is added to the JVM at runtime, what happens to the old loaded class? Does ClassA store which version of ClassB it first loaded? If it doesn't how does JVM know there is a signature difference and throw the error?

**Code used to add jars at runtime**

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});   //NO I18N
method.setAccessible(true);

File jarFolder = new File("<path-to-new-jar-folder>");
Collection<File> jarFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(jarFolder, new String[]{ "jar"}, true);         //NO I18N

for(File jarFile : jarFiles)
{
    method.invoke(urlClassLoader, jarFile.toURI().toURL());
}
```

**LinkageError**

> java.lang.LinkageError: 
>   loader constraint violation: 
>   when resolving method "org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.setEntity(Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;)V" 
>       the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) of the current class, 
>           com/application/rest/tokens/TokenHandler, 
>       and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) 
>           for the method's defining class, org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase, 
>       have different Class objects for the type org/apache/http/HttpEntity used in the signature

Comment: How do you "add more jars ... to the classpath at runtime" technically? To answer your question literally, nothing happens when you add a jar. The already loaded class is not affected at all and as long as you are speaking of a single class loader, there won't be a second class with the same name. This raises the question at the beginning of my comment, what you are actually doing, technically.

Comment: @Holger I have added the code I used to add jars to classpath at runtime.

Comment: Letting aside that this approach will stop working in Java 9, it shouldn’t break your code in the described way. It should have no effect on already loaded classes, in fact, it should not even alter the behavior when they are not loaded yet, as the `URLClassLoader` will simply search the URLs linearly for a class of the specified name, so in case of duplicates, the appended ones will never come to live. Can you add the exact `LinkageError` you get?

Comment: @Holger I have added the error message also. I'm getting this error only if ClassB is loaded into JVM before I add the new jars at runtime. If its not loaded before, then only the new jar added during runtime is considered.

Comment: Then, there’s something you didn’t tell us. According to the linkage error, the class in question has not been loaded from the class path, but a custom `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: The jar is set in classpath. I'm not sure how it is loaded because that must be handled by tomcat.

Comment: How about using `ClassInQuestion.class.getClassLoader()` instead of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`? Then, you don’t need to know how it works or which class loader it ends up. As a side effect, it would even work with Java 9+, as long as Tomcat doesn’t stop using `URLClassLoader`.

Comment: @Holger I'll try that but could you please explain what is the cause of this error and how does JVM know that the HttpEntity class first loaded and the HttpEntity class loaded now are different? Does it maintain the absolute path of the jar file from which it was loaded?

Comment: There are (at least) two different class loaders involved. Each class knows its defining class loader. In fact, belonging to different class loaders is the only way, how classes with the same name can live in the same JVM. The jar files are irrelevant. You can create two different class loaders using the same jar file and they will define distinct classes.

Comment: Ok. So, according to my example. Assume, TokenHandler and HttpEntity are loaded by ClassLoaderA and I'm loading the jars at runtime using ClassLoaderB. So, when I access TokenHandler again, shouldn't it work correctly because ClassLoaderA has already loaded the HttpEntity and required classes? Why should the HttpEntity in ClassLoaderB be a problem?

Comment: You are adding new jars to the system class loader, which is usually the *parent* of custom class loaders and hence, has precedence over the custom class loader. So new attempts to link a class, even from the custom class loader, will end up at the new class of the system class loader, which doesn’t match with the classes which have been already linked. Then, two classes, having a different opinion about what `HttpEntity` is, are trying to interact.

Comment: So the problem is both parent and child ClassLoaders having the same class. Only either of them should load the class. Is that right?

Comment: Right. Having only one version of the class should be the simplest fix. Since some the classes are potentially already loaded in your setup, it should be the class loader which did already load some of the classes, as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61753667/jvm-linkageerror-and-signature-difference#comment109259276_61753667)